# Is there a built-in Emacs Lisp form to only set a variable if it is unbound?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've created the following macro in elisp. It will set the value "val" to a variable "var" only if the variable is unbound. This exists so variables set in your .emacs file do not get trampled over somewhere else.

```
(defmacro set-ifunbound (var val)
  `(if (not (boundp ',var))
       (setq ,var ,val)
     (identity ,var)))
```

Surely, this has to be a common pattern. Is there a built in way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defvar` does exactly that. It assigns a value to a variable only if it's unbound.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I should have read the documentation. :) http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html